# The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

I am trying to use the following method in a WPF application `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` but I receive this error:

> *The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found*

I am using

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance

```
private async Task SumPageSizesAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Task<byte[]> getContentsTask = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    byte[] urlContents = await getContentsTask;   
}
```

I am using VS 2010

Comment: Make sure you aren't missing the return type: public static async void <<<<<

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, there are two things:

- You need to be using a C# 5 compiler, e.g. VS2012. If you're using VS2010, you can't use async. Given the error message, I suspect that you're using the wrong compiler version.
- You need to use the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to bring in the appropriate library support for .NET 4.

Comment: In case I use VS 2010 is this link appropriate http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983

Comment: @GibboK: Well it would be, but that's just a CTP, including known bugs. You should upgrade to VS2012, or accept that you won't be able to use async/await. I would *really* caution against using the CTP.

Comment: Information about Visual Studio and .NET versions which support async/await: http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs/html/32cc6156-3b31-4450-b209-b55fcfc0a210.htm

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue with the VS 2013 Syntax highlighting/checking, or if it is just correct. But if you create an async method in VS2013 without a return type (by mistake ofc!) it will also come up with this error when compiling and when highlighting. When what is actually wrong, is your method has no return type.

Comment: @KidCode: It could be either - because `async` is a valid type name, so you could be trying to write a method returning that type.

Answer (score 25):

In my case the return type was missing, message was cause by code:

```
private async button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and should be

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012+ and you stop typing the moment you get a red squiggley line, you may see this error message on the async keyword until you finish writing the method signature.

Finish writing the method signature, make sure there aren't any other compiler issues, and wait a second or so for Visual Studio to catch up.